# Stackdriver logging price in another region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

Does stackdriver logging on GCP cost more when it works on a region different than the targeted cluster's region?
I mean that my cluster in Europe, and my stackdriver logging and bucket on the US, is it cost more?

Comment: I would contact Google Cloud Billing support. The documentation for Operations logging does not mention region to region network cost but this is typically charged as "Egress between regions on another continent" for other services. The documentation is not specific on this point. The pricing calculator does not have a line item for network traffic.

Comment: This page can help you understand Operations Suite charges https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/estimating-bills

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to estimate cost of your storage buckets.
Pricing for transfer between regions can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing), and you can check logging pricing  [here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#logging-costs).
But, as mentioned, example scenarios do not cover situation in which bucket is located in different region, so it's best to reach out to [Cloud Billing Support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat?_ga=2.67736983.701027484.1614590334-943366271.1609237588&_gac=1.261668223.1614160492.Cj0KCQiAj9iBBhCJARIsAE9qRtBKatRRWATbwAgjf8Lf_QgrLxyScnbAO7wO2wdlghx2zJHnihHrZK4aAh9jEALw_wcB).